# Restrict the Width of a ContentPresenter's to its Dynamic Content

Tags: wpf, layout, contentpresenter

I would like to be able to dynamically adjust the size of a content control.

Here's a simple example:

```
...
<Slider x:Name="width" Minimum="40" Value="100" Maximum="300"/>
...
<ContentPresenter Width="{Binding Value, ElementName=width}" Content="Some value">
   <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid MaxWidth="200" MinWidth="80">
            <Rectangle Fill="Wheat" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Given this example, I would like to force the width of the content ContentPresenter to stay within the min and max width of its generated child (80 - 200 in this case).

Obviously with a simple example like this I could just change the range of the slider, but my real scenario is more complicated. I'm trying to restrict the size of a popup screen to its generated content. I can't set an explicit range on the popup because I have no idea what the content is going to be like before hand. The content has to be able to restrict itself.

Unfortunately MaxWidth and MinWidth on children are pretty much ignored. MinWidth results in cropping when the parent is set smaller. MaxWidth results in lots of empty space. It looks like I will have to set MaxWidth and MinWidth in the same place that I am dynamically updating the Width value.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to replace the ContentPresenter with a custom panel (alternately, enclose a custom panel in the ContentPresenter if you cannot replace it) that doles out the exact size you want in the way that you want.  It's fairly easy and simple to declare a class that derives from Panel and then override MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride.  In this case you could measure everything with the base MeasureOverride and then just assign the size you want as your available space.  In ArrangeOverride just assign the direct child of your panel, to be the final size of the panel (rect = 0,0,width,height).

Comment: Interesting thought. I'll look into this.